just-audio causing audio glitches or unexpected playback order
My Flutter audio playback code works well generally, but experiences issues when the pause and resume buttons are pressed simultaneously or within a very short interval. This seems to be related to the recursive nature of my playNextVoice() function, potentially causing audio glitches or unexpected playback order. How can I improve the code's robustness to handle these rapid button presses?"
here is my code snipet
  final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
  // Pause playback
  void pausePlayback() {
     player.playerStateStream.listen((state) async {
      if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
       await  player.pause();
      }
    });
    setState(() {
      isPaused = true; // Set the paused flag to true
      isPlaying = false; // Set isPlaying to false
    });
  }

  // Resume playback
  void resumePlayback() {
    setState(() {
      isPaused = false; // Set the paused flag to false
      isPlaying = true; // Set isPlaying to true
    });

    playNextVoice(); // Resume the voice playback
  }


  Future<void> playNextVoice() async {
     startTimer();
    if (isPaused) {
      return; // Stop recursion if paused
    }
    setState(() {
      showExtraButtons = false; // Hide extra buttons
      isPausedButtonDisabled = false; // Enable the Pause button
      isPlaying = true; // Set playing to true
      isPlayButtonDisabled = true; // Disable the Play button
    });

  shuffledVoices = List.from(bingoVoice)
      ..removeWhere((voice) => playedVoices.contains(voice))
      ..shuffle();

    if (shuffledVoices.isEmpty) {
      await player.dispose(); // Dispose the player when done
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = false;
        showExtraButtons = true;
        isPausedButtonDisabled = true;
      });
      return;
    }

    currentFileName = shuffledVoices.removeAt(0);
    playedVoices.add(currentFileName!);

    String filePath = widget.selectedCheckBoxIndex == 0
        ? "bingoVoice/$currentFileName"
        : widget.selectedCheckBoxIndex == 1
            ? "bingoVoice2_single/$currentFileName"
            : "bingoVoice2_double/$currentFileName";

    try {
      await player.setAsset(filePath); // Load the audio
      await player.play(); // Start playback

      String identifier = currentFileName!.split('.').first;
      widget.onSecondMethodCalled(identifier);

      player.playerStateStream.listen((state) async {
        if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
          playNextVoice(); // Play the next voice
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error playing audio: $e");
      playNextVoice(); // Skip to the next voice on error
    }
  }

